# Flutter: List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> when parsing JSON

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dart

I've got a problem with parsing JSON to dart object.
This is the class which object I try to get.

```
    class CardDetails {
      String cardId;
      /*
      some fields
      /*
      List<Mechanics> mechanics;
    
      CardDetails(
          {this.cardId,
          /*
          some fields
          /*
          this.mechanics});
    
      CardDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        cardId = json['cardId'];
      /*
      some fields
      /*
        if (json['mechanics'] != null) {
          mechanics = new List<Mechanics>();
          json['mechanics'].forEach((v) {
            mechanics.add(new Mechanics.fromJson(v));
          });
        }
      }
    }
    
    class Mechanics {
      String name;
    
      Mechanics({this.name});
    
      Mechanics.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        name = json['name'];
      }
    }
```

And this is a method to get response from API.

```
Future<CardDetails> getCardDetails(String cardId) async {
    Response res = await get(cardDetailsURL + cardId, headers: headers);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      return CardDetails.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load details');
    }
  }
```

As far as I know getting response works fine.

And this is example JSON

```
[
    {
        "cardId": "hexfrog",
        "dbfId": "548",
        "name": "Frog",
        "cardSet": "Basic",
        "type": "Minion",
        "faction": "Neutral",
        "rarity": "Common",
        "attack": 0,
        "health": 1,
        "text": "<b>Taunt</b>",
        "race": "Beast",
        "playerClass": "Neutral",
        "img": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/hexfrog.png",
        "imgGold": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/animated/hexfrog_premium.gif",
        "locale": "enUS",
        "mechanics": [
            {
                "name": "Taunt"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But parsing doesn't work and I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(213)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON are a `List` since it begins with `[`.

Comment: So it should work when i change `return CardDetails.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));` to `return CardDetails.fromJson(json.decode(res.body[0]));` for example?

Comment: No, because body are a String so if you are calling [0] on this String you will just get the first letter. But you can do `CardDetails.fromJson(json.decode(res.body)[0]);` . Here we still parse the JSON but takes the first element of the list and send it to `CardDetails.fromJson`.

Comment: Ok, please accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you are parsing is a `List` of maps but in your code you are expecting just a map. If you know the JSON will always just return a single element you can do the following:

```
CardDetails.fromJson(json.decode(res.body)[0]);
```